# Jquery Disappear div after my form is posted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm just wondering how to disappear div object during submitting.

When I try to click submit button, Div object does not hide directly.
The confirm event always do the job prior to hiding of div.

e.g.

```
$("#button").click(function(){
   $(".div").hide(); // step 1.
   var fl = confirm("Do you want to apply this?"); // step 2.
   if(fl){
       bla bla bla....
   }
});
```

I've leaned that step 1 have to be activated for the first time,
step 2's action fired then.

But you know Step 2 is always run ahead of step 1.
What is my problem?
I really want to resolve this issue :)

Test environment is PC and MAC not mobile devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to call back.

see here http://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-duration-complete

```
$("#button").click(function(){
   $(".div").hide("200", YourFunction()); // step 1.
});

function YourFunction() {
   var fl = confirm("Do you want to apply this?"); // step 2.
   if(fl){
       bla bla bla....
   }
}
```

**EDIT :**

or you can do that

```
 $("#button").click(function(){
     $(".div").hide( "slow", function() {
       var fl = confirm("Do you want to apply this?"); // step 2.
       if(fl){
           bla bla bla....
       }
     }); // step 1.
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, you should give id to your div rather than class,so that you can target specific div.Try this :

HTML:

```
<div id="colorDiv" class=".color">
  Hello
</div>

<button id="submit">
```

JS :

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
   alert("Are you Sure you want to remove??");
   $("#colorDiv").hide();
});
```

This will solve your problem, for working fiddle check this [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/68pyjc7y/)

Comment: Thank you for your attention to this matter :)